# Non capturing look behind in regex python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to extract net profit from the statement, with 'net profit' as the non capturing part. Not sure how to do it(may be a non capturing look behind?)

eg

> 'business venture of net profit 23.5 million dollars'

required o/p:

> 23.5 million

Applied the following regex:

```
(net|nt)\s*\.?\s*(profit|earnings)\s*\.?\s*\d+\.?\d*\.?\s*(?:lakh|crore|million)
```

But, it is giving

> [('net', 'profit')]

as the output.

Comment: Yes, you have groups that capture. Did you look at the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and find the lookbehind assertion syntax (`(?<=...)`) yet? IIRC you can't use variable-width patterns (`*` specifically) in an assertion like that however. Perhaps you just wanted t omake the groups *non-capturing* (like the group you put after)?

Comment: You can use [`ne?t\s*\.?\s*(?:profit|earnings)\s*(\.?\s*\d+\.?\d*\.?\s*(?:lakh|crore|million))`](https://regex101.com/r/7yw1pn/1)

Comment: Aditya, doesn't [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43973389/3832970) work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below regex you will get the result in group 1,

```
(?:ne?t\s(?:profit|earning)\s)([\d\.]+\s(?:million|laks|crore))
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/cVYnhq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?:)` for non-capture

```
s = 'business venture of net profit 23.5 million dollars'
re.findall(r'(?:net|nt)\s*\.?\s*(?:profit|earnings)\s*\.?\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\.?\s*(lakh|crore|million)',s)
[('23.5', 'million')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't capture the digitgroup. Also you need a non-capturing group with the 'net' and 'profit'

so this should work:

**Edit** to capture million..etc

```
import re
s = 'business venture of net profit 23.5 million dollars'
re.findall(r'(?:net|nt)\s*\.?\s*(?:profit|earnings)\s*\.?\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\.?\s*(lakh|crore|million)', s)
# output: ['23.5', 'million']
```

Example at:
https://regex101.com/r/EXCzeV/2

Comment: how to include 'million' in the output?

Comment: Remove the non-capturing group which corresponds to : `(lakh|core|million)`